# Magento 2.3.4: Refresh window.checkoutConfig

Tags: magento2.3, php, checkout, javascript, knockoutjs

We are adding shipping price of quote object to `myTestData` which is pulled onto the page using `window.checkoutConfig.myTestData`:

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Config implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
  protected $checkoutSession;

  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
  ) {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
  }

  /* Get Quote */
  public function getQuote()
  {
    return $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
  }

  /* Return Config Details */
  public function getConfig()
  {
    $config = [];
    $config['myTestData'] = $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();

    return $config;
  }
```

This returns the proper shipping amount on first load of the cart, but if we change shipping method, `myTestData` does not get updated to reflect the new value. How can we make sure `window.checkoutConfig.myTestData` gets refreshed if / when cart is updated?

EDIT, if not using checkoutConfig, is there another way to pass dynamic block variables to javascript object any time the cart updates?

Comment: if my answer helped kindly accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP functions run when page is reload so you can do this in you custom controller what ever you want

steps

1. create a ajax call on shipping select to a controller

like on shipping select radio button add

`onlick="myfunction()`"

and in js file use like this

```
   function myfunction() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/routename/controller_folder/controller_file',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            yourvariable: your_variable_value
        },
        complete: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
```

2. in your controller get that value in execute function like

   $yourvariable = $this->getRequest()->getParam('yourvariable');

now do what ever you like with this variable

By this when ever the shipping method changes it will call that ajax with updated JS variable

hope you get my point if need more details feel free to comment if helps then up-vote please

Comment: Thanks @Asad, using this would it be possible to update checkoutConfig.myTestData with updated value?  I any case, this does give me a bit of a better idea on some things to try.

Comment: i think if you send that param with ajax call it will update on every click so you will get that updated value in controller

Comment: The checkout is built with UI Components so I recommend using those not jQuery, else you may end up in a situation where jQuery and Knockout are conflicting.

Comment: Thanks @AsadUllah this ended up working by creating a controller and calling that via ajax and binding that to checkout button.

Comment: "binding that to checkout button." how did you do this?

Comment: @Jack like this <input type="password" data-bind="value: userPassword" />

Comment: For me, I need to update order total weight and need to show in summary block, but it's not updated when i change it via ajax fro  checkout session

Comment: have you tried refresh summary block div after ajax call?i hope if your ajax is working fine then you need to refresh summary block div also to check updated result